# itext android some characters not shown

Tags: java, android, pdf, character-encoding, itext

I am using itext pdf library in android to generate some pdf's. 
It has been added to the project through gradle and the version i'm using is **5.5.10**

Everything works perfectly when only english characters are printed in to the pdf. The problems start to occur when I try to add Norweigian characters (example: **å**, **æ**, **ø**, **è** etc..).

Everything works perfectly except for those characters, I am getting an empty space instead.

I have googled all around and spent 2 days but nothing is working.
Following is the code that I am trying to use:

```
    String FONT = "FreeSans.ttf";
    String RESULT = "test.pdf";
    BaseFont font = BaseFont.createFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    // step 1
    Document document = new Document();
    // step 2
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));
    // step 3
    document.open();
    // step 4
    document.add(new Paragraph("Sandem g\u00c5rd", new Font(font, 20)));
    // step 5
    document.close();
```

After a lot of frustration I decided to try the same code on pure java (NO ANDROID).

I created a new project with intelliJ and imported the same library from maven **com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10**

And guess what with pure JAVA it worked on the first run. The character **Å** (Unicode character: **u+00c5**) is displayed correctly!
That is really strange! Same code same version of the library and it works with java only but not with android!

I also tried changing many fonts but no luck! 
If i try to print a paragraph without adding the font parametre instead of an empty space i get some strange characters.

One more weird behaviour was encountered when I tried to use the font **AbhayaLibret**. Using this exact font i could see the **å** character and the other special ones but only those one! The normal english character were not shown with this font! This is again really strange behaviour!

At this point I am starting to suspect that something is going wrong with the bundling of the font file in to the android .apk package or maybe its not parsed correctly!

Or maybe I am doing something wrong?

**UPDATE**
I forgot to mention that at some point I tried to print Hindi language characters using unicode and those worked perfectly! That is again really strange because those unicode codes are printed correctly but not the one I am trying to use.

Comment: Try by just adding some short hard-coded things. Ref :  https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-11#434-encodingexample.java

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse sorry for the wrong typing but I meant com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10.

Comment: @VVB I tried and this is the result


Using Java only (Correct Result): https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9wm7Vc7aBf8blhGTFQ4T18wd28/view?usp=sharing


Using Android (Problem still there):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9wm7Vc7aBf8cTBydGJ3emYzLVk/view?usp=sharing



PDF File generated with android:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9wm7Vc7aBf8QjltUTR2aGpJaFE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @VVB any suggestions?